# Gmail's quick action buttons implementation

Tags: gmail

How can I implement quick action buttons for gmail on email templates?
My goal is basically focused only on users that have a gmail account.
I saw the news about quick action buttons for gmail and I want to know how to implement those so the newsletters/emails on gmail have the quick action buttons appearing. This will definitely increase the conversion of users acting upon email delivery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/introducing-actions-in-inbox-powered-by.html . It seems it just needs a JSON-LD markup added to the email templates :

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "schema.org",
  "@type": "Movie",
  "name": "The Internship",
  ... information about the movie ...
  "action": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Add to queue",
    "actionHandler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://my-movies.com/add?movieId=123",
      "method": "POST",
    }
  }
}
</script>
```